# JUnit in ANT giving ClassNotFoundException

Tags: junit, ant, junit4, ant-junit

I am trying to run a simple junit in a package. But it keeps on failing with ClassNotFound Exception.
My build file looks like this:

```
<project name="JunitTest" default="test" basedir=".">
<property name="testdir" location="bin" />
<property name="full-compile" value="true" />
<path id="classpath.base"/>
<path id="classpath.test">
  <pathelement location="lib/junit-4.10.jar" />
  <pathelement location="${testdir}" />
  <path refid="classpath.base" />
</path>
<target name="test">
  <junit  fork="no">
     <classpath refid="classpath.test" />
     <formatter type="brief" usefile="false" />
     <test name="Test" />
  </junit>
</target>
</project>
```

And my Test.java looks like this:

```
package com.org.test.data.mine.board;

import org.junit.Test;

public class Test {

@Test
public void testDummy() {

    System.out.println("Hello");
}

}
```

And this keeps on failing with:

```
test:
[junit] Testsuite: Test
[junit] Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0 sec
[junit]
[junit] Null Test:  Caused an ERROR
[junit] Test
[junit] java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Test
[junit]     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
[junit]     at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
[junit]     at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:274)
[junit]
[junit]
[junit] Test Test FAILED
```

I looked through other SO posts but couldn't recognize the issue. Help!!

Answer (score 1):

There is a problem in the way you have written name of your `Test class`. You need to modify your `jUnit task` to include FQCN like this:

```
  <junit  fork="no">
     <classpath refid="classpath.test" />
     <formatter type="brief" usefile="false" />
     <test name="com.org.test.data.mine.board.Test" />
  </junit>
```